# FEM textbooks recommendation

Tags: finite-element

I would really appreciate if you could recommend me some textbooks that explain FEM process well and have many exercises to solidify the knowledge. So far, Brenner and Zienkiewicz seem to be a bit hard, although, I would like to switch to Zienkiewicz, once I get the grasp of the basics. Any input would be greatly appreciated.

I want to be experienced in solving PDEs using FEM manually, without using software tools right now. That is my goal right now.

Answer (score 4):

I like the book by Elman, Silvester, and Wathen, "Finite elements and fast iterative solvers" quite a lot.

Comment: Seconding this one. It describes how to use FEM on a wide variety of problem types with continued emphasis on practical implementations and solution tools.

Answer (score 2):

Consider reading the first chapter of [the Hughes book](https://www.google.co.in/books/edition/The_Finite_Element_Method/yarmSc7ULRsC?hl=en). It has a lot of exercises, though I don't know how to get hold of the instructor's manual. Perhaps [Schaum's outline](https://www.amazon.in/SCHAUMS-OUTLINE-FINITE-ELEMENT-ANALYSIS/dp/9389691370) will help, though I haven't used it.

Answer (score 1):

In my studies, the finite element method was covered from the math's point of view in a mathematics lecture. Over the course of a semester, we heard about the underlying math and in a accompanying practical exercise, we even programmed our own simple finite element solution in Matlab/Octave if I remember correctly.

So, you could expand your search into lecture material for numerical methods in engineering, numerical methods and optimization, or any other lectures with a similar scope.

Unfortunately, I can not share the lecture material of the lecture I allude to, for legal reasons (copyright) and for language reasons (this was all in German). However, my anecdote hopefully gives you a new direction to investigate.

Answer (score 1):

I found [these](https://users.metu.edu.tr/csert/teaching_notes.htm) to be very helpful. Check Lecture Notes for ME 582 chapter 3 for example.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: Would still encourage you to get more into the theory through the text books mentioned above when you get the hang of this